# problem connecting to red5 "firstApp" from librtmp

Tags: red5, rtmp

I am trying to connect to Red5 tutorial "firstApp" application from libRTMP client.
Note that I can connect to it from flex client, as tutorial describes:

```
...
//from flex client 
NetConnection nc = new NetConnection();
nc.connect("rtmp://localhost/firstApp"); - connected, works

//from libRTMP

RTMP* r = RTMP_Alloc();
retVal = RTMP_SetupURL(r, "rtmp://localhost/firstApp");
retVal = RTMP_Connect(r, NULL); - no connection

retVal = RTMP_SetupURL(r, "rtmp://localhost:1935/firstApp");
retVal = RTMP_Connect(r, NULL); - still no connection

//The same thing works fine for Red5 "live" application

retVal = RTMP_SetupURL(r, "rtmp://localhost:1935/live/instance");
retVal = RTMP_Connect(r, NULL); - works, connected
```

Any ideas what the problem might be? 
Thank you,
-V

Answer (score 0):

Can you take a look at logs? Perhaps librtmp still send "live" as a name of application.

Answer (score 0):

Is there an installed and configured application named "firstApp" inside your red5 webapps directory?

Comment: Can you take a look at logs? Perhaps librtmp still send "live" as a name of application.
No, I checked with wireshark...
Is there an installed and configured application named "firstApp" inside your red5 webapps directory?
Yes

Answer (score 0):

try "rtmp://localhost/firstApp/*definst*" as the URL

Answer (score 0):

The RTMP URL format is of the form

```
rtmp[t][e|s]://hostname[:port][/app[/playpath]]
```

Reference : http://rtmpdump.mplayerhq.hu/librtmp.3.html

Answer (score 0):

Eventually solved my problems with another open source RTMP project "crtmpserver" (http://www.rtmpd.com), which seems to be far better designed, documented, implemented and maintained.